# Linking an XSD file to XML

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

I am new to XML and I am looking to link my schema to my xml file but I am receiving the following error using http://www.xpathtester.com/validate

ERROR - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Courier'.

the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Courier xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="courier.xsd">
    //Omitted code
    </Courier>
```

The .xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</xs:schema>
```

I've looked around at various answers related to this question but I don't understand what parts of their answers are required.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xsd schema you don't have any "Courier" element. you need to add something like `<xs:element name="Courier">` in your xsd file.

Comment: Oh that would make sense. I just assumed it was a namespace problem since I don't really understand those. Thanks.